# Are the Targaryens connected to the Lord of Light religion?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

The Targaryens control fire breathing dragons and are not harmed by fire. The Lord of Light is a fire god and fire is used in worship/magic by it's followers.

The Targaryens came from Valyria, where the LoL cult is quite common.

Are the two related somehow?

Comment: [Targaryens are not immune to fire.](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/37473/21267)

Comment: @mooz he also said Dany probably couldn't do it again, yet here we are, in season 6.

Comment: @cde The show's interpretation of this scene has always been that **Dany is immune to fire**, which is fine for the show; however the books are less definitive about this. Also, Dany is no "regular" Targaryen, her fire scenes are unique occurrences.

Comment: @Mooz Dany said that if her brother was a true dragon, he wouldn't had been harmed by the molten gold. I took that to mean that a true Targaryen is immune to fire. On multiple occasions the show mentions that the Targaryens rode dragons and intermarried for generations to keep their blood pure - I think it's safe to assume that as far as the show is concerned at least some of them should be immune to fire.

Comment: @ventsyv Dany is not very well educated. Her primary source of education has always been Viserys (who is an idiot).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there's no significant connection between them. In fact, the Targaryen's didn't even worship R'hllor at all.

In the show we haven't heard very much about Valyria in it's prime (yet), but I was unable to find any evidence that R'hllor worship was common in Valyria before it exploded. Valyria instead had it's own religion, where the people worshiped a Pantheon of gods. In the novels, we are told that the Targaryen's named their dragons after these Old Gods, e.g. Balerion, Meraxes, Vhagar and Syrax. Otherwise, though, the Targaryen's were mostly non-religious, but adopted most of the customs of the Faith of the Seven when they conquered Westeros.

The fact that both are strongly connected to fire appears to be simply the nature of fire as a primal force, so it's a recurring motif with different meanings in different situations.

Comment: In Westeros, they followed the Faith of the Seven.

Comment: I though their powers might come from R'hllor or the cult's magic somehow.